# How to make IF statement in old version of Maria DB(MYSQL)-ver 10.4.15

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am trying to make simple logic inside my Maria DB and failed.
Looks like my Maria DB version does not support `if` statements.
I am trying to do something like :

```
set @operationId = (select id from operation where domainName = 'newOperation'); 

INSERT INTO system (operationId, name, description, createdBy, version) 
VALUES (@operationId, 'newSystem', 'New System', 'Me', 1);
```

The problem is sometimes the `@operationId` and if so I would like to skip the if statement. Something like  :

```
set @operationId = (select id from operation where domainName = 'newOperation'); 
IF ( @operationId is not null )
INSERT INTO system (operationId, name, description, createdBy, version) 
VALUES (@operationId, 'newSystem', 'New System', 'Me', 1);
```

but my Maria DB version does not support it...

any idea how i can do it ?
Thanks

Comment: Yes it does but only with the correct syntax and only on stored routines. see manual for syntax. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/if/

Comment: Hi , from what i understood it support only on higher version. i know it is not the syntax - was just writing what i would like in general. can you direct me ? what is store routines ?

Comment: stored routine - procedure,function,trigger,event.   'from what i understood it support only on higher version.'? where do you understand this from?

Comment: maybe i did not understand right....so my problem is that i am trying to do it on regular queries and not SP/Function etc ?

Comment: You cannot use control flow statements in plain sql scripts, only in stored programmes. End of story. Either you have to use a workaround as suggested by jarlh in the answer below, or you need to use stored programme, or you need to implement the logic in application code.

Comment: @shadow hmm https://mariadb.com/kb/en/using-compound-statements-outside-of-stored-programs/ and https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=d6da9b168d0bfd3a1beba02f89cbd2fc works in 10.4.22 but not apparently in 10.4.15

Comment: ok , will try to create function. thank u !

Comment: so in new version it does support...thought i saw it also...

Comment: Actually is supported on 10.3 too - so what is your exact code?

Answer (score 0):

No need for an `IF`, simply do `INSERT` with `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO system (operationId, name, description, createdBy, version) 
  select id, 'newSystem', 'New System', 'Me', 1
  from operation where domainName = 'newOperation'
```

(If the `SELECT` can return several rows, consider to do `SELECT DISTINCT` instead.)

Comment: thank u for the reply ...it was just an example...i would need to add different values via the insert and as our B is not sync in some versions i would like the script to run and in others-do not. my main goal is have the ability the due insert only is some cases and not always by the return value i got in @operationId